# load a page on a specific date with checkdate, if not redirect it

Tags: php

I want, that my page can only be loaded on a specific date. If not, redirect so another one. I found out, that this is possible with checkdate, but as a php newbie, I don't know what to do.
It should be as simple as:
checkdate -> valid -> load page
checkdate -> invalid -> redirect to example.php
Can someone push me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isValidDate($sd, $ed, $currentDate = null)
{
    if ($currentDate === null) {
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
    }

    return ($currentDate >= $sd && $currentDate <= $ed);
}

$startDate = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
$endDate   = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
if (isValidDate($startDate, $endDate)) {
    // show page
} else {
    // redirect to example.php
}
```